# php: how to decrement date time into a foreach for every item...?

Tags: php, datetime, foreach, decrement

... and not one time only...

```
    $now = date("D, d M Y H:i:s O");
    foreach ($items AS $item)
        {

            $currentDate = strtotime($now);
            $pastDate = $currentDate-(60*5);
            $formatDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $pastDate);
            echo "\t\t<item>\n";
            echo "\t\t\t<pubDate>" . $formatDate . "</pubDate>\n" ;
```

now, i want formatDate decrementing of 5 minutes every time, i don't want the same time for every element... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$currentDate = time();
foreach ($items as $item){
    $formatDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDate);
    echo "\t\t<item>\n";
    echo "\t\t\t<pubDate>" . $formatDate . "</pubDate>\n" ;
    $currentDate = strtotime('-5 minutes', $currentDate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original idea of subtracting (60*5) was exactly right; you just need to keep subtracting it from a working value, rather than repeatedly subtracting it from the original value as per your code:

```
$looptime = time();
foreach ($items AS $item) {
    $looptime -= (60*5);
    $formatDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $looptime);
    echo "\t\t<item>\n";
    echo "\t\t\t<pubDate>" . $formatDate . "</pubDate>\n" ;
}
```

Comment: I think people are so enchanted with how 'magic' strtotime() is, they just want to use it over and over and over and over ...

Comment: @Mark B - yes, it's bizarre. `strtotime()` is a horrible function; should be used as little as possible. Fortunately, I note that everyone who recommended it has now either changed their mind or deleted their answers, so I've removed that remark from my answer.

Comment: eheheh but why is it horrible?

Comment: hey, and instead... if i want to randomize the same (-5 minutes) time for every item??? That is, the -5 decrement is good, but not always starting from the 1st item, i would it random for all elements into the array...

Comment: ok, nevermind...i used `shuffle($items);` unless you have a better way

Comment: @smepie - `strtotime()` is horrible when it's used for maths, like ths simple subtraction in this question. It's bad in that context because it's doing a huge amount of processing and type conversion for something that should be a simple math function. In general, `strtotime()` has issues with being overcomplex and not always getting the right result if the date format given is ambiguous. I make it a rule to avoid `strtotime()`, unless its a last resort. Any time `strtottime()` seems like the answer, there is usually a better answer to be had.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.3 you should check [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime). It allows you to create an object for a specific time, and it has a `sub()` method that you can use to decrement the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = time();
foreach ($items AS $item)
    {
        echo "\t\t<item>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<pubDate>" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $now) . "</pubDate>\n" ;
        echo "\t\t</item>\n";
        $now -= (60*5);
    }
```